# Is this plant Giant Hogweed?

Tags: identification, weed-control

In getting our spring landscaping underway, we've run into a bush that a family member is sure that this plant (pictured) is Giant Hogweed.

*Click photo for full size*
[image: Photo of the weed]

British Columbia considers this plant to be toxic (if it is indeed that species) and requires a professional to be called in to remediate.

I've tried to find samples online, and there are similarities, but I also don't have enough background knowledge in plants to be sure.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes the lower leaves don't look like Giant Hogweed to me. Hogweed is an invasive in the UK as well, and I remember warnings to school kids in the 80s. My understanding is that the only 'toxic' problem is that the sap sensitises the skin esp. to sunlight. The end result resembles a chemical burn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Myrrhis odorata, aka Sweet Cicely. The entire plant is mildly liquorice-scented.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicely

Comment: Thanks - it was confirmed as Myrrhis odorata by a landscaper (and he pointed out the liquorice scent too!).  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure this is [Cow Parsley (*Anthriscus sylvestris*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthriscus_sylvestris), an invasive but non-toxic weed, not [Giant Hogweed (*Heracleum mantegazzianum*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracleum_mantegazzianum).

Differences between the two include:

- **Leaf structure**: Cow Parsley's leaves are fernlike, Giant Hogweed's leaves are much larger and coarser:

  *Cow parsley leaves*
  [image]

  *Giant Hogweed leaves:*
  [image]
- **Height**: Cow Parsley grows to about 3' to 4' in height (1m to 1.3m), Giant Hogweed grows to 7' to 15' / 2m to 4.5m, though Wikipedia says it can grow higher.
- **Stems**: both plants have hollow stems, but Giant Hogweed has dark reddish spots on its stems.  Cow Parsley's stems are green and fluted.
- **Habitat**: Giant Hogweed likes a wet environment; you can typically see it in the wild along riverbanks or in marshy ground.  Cow Parsley is more of a meadow wildflower.

Comment: +1 for good side-by-side images illustrating the difference between these two plants and comparison of the two plants.

Comment: It looks very similar to poison hemlock.  http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=9975

Comment: @thomasw_lrd The seed pods are different though; see the illustrations on the Wikipedia pages for [Poison Hemlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conium) and [Cow Parsley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthriscus_sylvestris)